# getting a None value and i don't know why

Tags: python-2.7

```
def getUsername():
username = raw_input("Enter Your Username: ")
if not username[0].isalpha():
    print "wrong"
    getUsername()
else:
    return username
```

am trying to check if the first char of the string username is a alphabetical char and if it's not to ask the user for hes user name again and if it is set it to username.

but when i run though the function more the once i get back the value None from username what i mean by that is when i run the function and give it a bad value once it works fine and asks me again for a value but when i print out the value i get back a None.

can you please tell me why.

and of course how to fix it
thanks in the advance :

Comment: As a side note, using a recursive function for this seems over the top when you could just use a loop to check.

Comment: Use a `while True` loop http://pastebin.com/0DnXSVXe

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `return` in your recursive call to `getUsername()`:

```
def getUsername():
    username = raw_input("Enter Your Username: ")
    if not username[0].isalpha():
        print "wrong"
        return getUsername()
    else:
        return username
```

Without it your function recursively calls `getUsername()`, exits the if/else block and falls off from the function, which implicitly returns `None`.

From the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> None
>
> This type has a single value. There is a single object with this value. This object is accessed through the built-in name None. It is used to signify the absence of a value in many situations, e.g., **it is returned from functions that don’t explicitly return anything.** Its truth value is false.

On [defining functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions):

> The return statement returns with a value from a function. **`return` without an expression argument returns None. Falling off the end of a function also returns None.**

Answer (score 0):

Why even use a recursive Function for this just use a while Loop.

```
def getUname():
    while True:
        username = raw_input("name:");
        if not username[0].isalpha():
            print "wrong";
        else:
            return username;
```

it should return the same.

Comment: how these the function know to break out of the loop and not run forever i see no break or anything to make the loop stop can you please explain this ?

Comment: `return` in any loop breaks the loop and return to the previous function. Not just loop if a `return` is occurred anywhere in a code block the codes after return are never reached.